# How to Create an Account With Github on Meteor

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I am currently developing a project with Meteor and React and I was trying to add GitHub authentication. I'm not getting any errors, but when I click the GitHub login, it simply opens the authentication page and closes it immediately and the login status doesn't change (reference: https://www.novaterra.earth/signup).

I'm using Meteor.loginWithGithub() for this, but do I need to run a sign in method first? I've set up all the authentication on Github and when I clicked the popup, it looked like it did create the account:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_0ZQMMbH2KusJvrZlzhEU15Uh8uQSlze/view?usp=sharing

Yet on my application there was no change in the login status and my database (mlab) didn't show a new user added.

My code looks like this:

*Signup.js:*

```js
<div onClick={() => this.gitHubLogin()} className="signup__loginWithGithub">
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fab', 'github']} className={`signup__loginWithGoogleIcon`} />
<div className="signup__loginWithGoogleText">Sign in With Github</div></div>

gitHubLogin() {
  Meteor.loginWithGithub({
      requestPermissions: ['user'],
  }, function (err) {
    console.log('is there an error?', err);
  });
}
```

*Main.js (Server):*

```js
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
  service: "github"
});
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
  service: "github" ,
  loginStyle: "popup",
  clientId: "xxx",
  secret: "xxx"
});
```

So, in summary, I was expecting to have this code create a new account on my application and be signed in, yet for some reason, I only had a popup flash and nothing else happened.

If you have any other questions, please don't hesitate in asking!

Thank you for your help,

Oliver